# Wordpress Elementor Upload on another Server resets CSS Styles

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting, elementor, ddev

Hey I have a ddev instance of my wordpress website.

If I Upload my stuff via phpmyadmin and SFTP to a Webhost called one.com or Ionos.de, everything works fine and styles are loaded.

As soon as I try to change something with the elementor frontend editor, all my .css styles get a reset and I cant save it because all my styles would be gone. It seems elementor frontend editor cant find or load the uploaded CSS.

Anybody got an Idea why I have this weird behaviour ?

Wordpress
Elementor
DDEV

Comment: You mention [DDEV](https://ddev.com). Is this problem happening to you when using DDEV? Or just when you're working on the internet websites  `one.com` or `lonos.de` ?

Comment: @rfay Thanks for your reply. It just happens on the server itself.
My Upload process is I export via `ddev tableplus` and import via phpmyadmin.
The rest is uploaded via ssh and a simple rsync.
I also created a second ddev instance to double check the problem. It is working there..

Comment: You probably are not uploading a directory where the CSS goes, or the source of the CSS, or you need a deploy step that generates the CSS.

Comment: ok i believe it has something to do with the rights on the server OR my rsync and files are left behind

the directory wp-content/uploads/elementor/css is important for elementor
for every page elementor is doing a postXX.css file and also has a global.css file

But when using the elementor editor there is no css file used. Instead there are <style> attributes and these ones are missing or simply wrong on the server.